# What regression approach does tensorflow's DNNRegressor apply under the hood?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

I want to understand what kind of regression does the DNNRegressor estimator apply in the background, specifically is it linear?

Comment: You can find some information here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253337/what-is-the-difference-between-regular-linear-regression-and-deep-learning-lin?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

No it is not linear, at least not in general. Like the name suggests it is a DNN (deep [neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network)).

Usually a crucial point of neural networks is to not be linear, even though technically a simple linear regressor might be considered a neural network without hidden layers and linear activation, most people (including me) would not call that a neural network though.

Like the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNRegressor) clearly states, this class is deprecated and should therefore not be used anymore in new code.